# XML and C# Read Header Info

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have an XML file that has some header info and then long list(s) of name / value pairs. I can read the name value pairs just fine - once I know their node names.

These are like:

```
<Doubler_Cal>
  <Freq>300000000</Freq> 
  <Mag>14.71725</Mag> 
</Doubler_Cal>
<Doubler_Cal>
  <Freq>310000000</Freq> 
  <Mag>15.25</Mag> 
</Doubler_Cal>
<Doubler_Cal>
  <Freq>320000000</Freq> 
  <Mag>16.25</Mag> 
</Doubler_Cal>
.
.
.
<Tripler_Stuff>
  <Freq>300000000</Freq> 
  <Mag>13.8</Mag> 
</Tripler_Stuff>
<Tripler_Stuff>
  <Freq>310000000</Freq> 
  <Mag>10.15</Mag> 
</Tripler_Stuff>
.
.
.
```

Etc.....

And I can read them with an XML doc reader like this,

```
XmlNodeList nodes=doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Doubler_Cal");
```

or

```
XmlNodeList nodes=doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Tripler_stuff");
```

No problem there..... **If I know the names** of these nodes (i.e. "Doubler_Cal", "Tripler_Stuff"... etc.)

The problem I am having is trying to figure out how to read the header info in the XML document that I have. In the header is a list of the value pairs names that the XML document contains.

The header looks like this (See complete snippet below)...

The node names I'm trying to parse here would be the,

```
<xs:element name="Doubler_Cal">
<xs:element name="Tripler_Stuff">
<xs:element name="This_too_is_possible">
<xs:element name="YetAnotherName">
```

to yield a string array containing:
"Doubler_Cal",
"Tripler_Stuff",
"This_too_is_possible",
"YetAnotherName".

Once I know these, I can use my "one working" line of code to get all the value pairs for that particular name.

Here is a post of the more complete XML file - It does not contain all the value pairs as there would be 100's of these. But should be enough to figure out what is going on.

```
<NewDataSet>
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Doubler_Cal">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Freq" type="xs:double" />
                <xs:element name="Mag" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="Tripler_Stuff">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Freq" type="xs:double" />
                <xs:element name="Mag" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="This_too_is_possible">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Freq" type="xs:double" />
                <xs:element name="Mag" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="YetAnotherName">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Freq" type="xs:double" />
                <xs:element name="Mag" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <Doubler_Cal>
    <Freq>300000000</Freq>
    <Mag>14.71725</Mag>
  </Doubler_Cal>
  <Doubler_Cal>
    <Freq>310000000</Freq>
    <Mag>15.25</Mag>
  </Doubler_Cal>
  <Doubler_Cal>
    <Freq>320000000</Freq>
    <Mag>16.25</Mag>
  </Doubler_Cal>
  <Tripler_Stuff>
    <Freq>300000000</Freq>
    <Mag>13.8</Mag>
  </Tripler_Stuff>
  <Tripler_Stuff>
    <Freq>310000000</Freq>
    <Mag>10.15</Mag>
  </Tripler_Stuff>
  <This_too_is_possible>
    <Freq>322000000</Freq>
    <Mag>17.25</Mag>
  </This_too_is_possible>
  <This_too_is_possible>
    <Freq>332000000</Freq>
    <Mag>18.8</Mag>
  </This_too_is_possible>
  <This_too_is_possible>
    <Freq>334000000</Freq>
    <Mag>19.15</Mag>
  </This_too_is_possible>
  <YetAnotherName>
    <Freq>322000000</Freq>
    <Mag>17.25</Mag>
  </YetAnotherName>
  <YetAnotherName>
    <Freq>332000000</Freq>
    <Mag>18.8</Mag>
  </YetAnotherName>
</NewDataSet>
```

**Thanks for the help, I appreciate it.**

Comment: The document you have posted is not well formed.  Can you post the entire original unmodified document?  If you are concerned about pretty-print, don't be.

Comment: A *complete* example would be ideal.  It's not clear how the `NewDataSet` element containing a schema relates to the elements you're actually trying to read.  Are they in the same document?  Are there any other elements in the content or the schema you are *not* interested in?  It's very hard to give an answer without a complete picture of what's going on.

Comment: The xml you post is still not well formed.  Either it is an incomplete sample, or it is getting mangled somewhere else.  For example, the `xs` namespace is not declared, the `xs:choice` tag is missing a `>`, and you have no `xs:schema` or `xs:element` tags.

Comment: Yep.  It's a dataset.  See my answer for how to load it as such.

Comment: Thank you Charles and Mitch for the help. I think the example file is now correctly matched and formatted. It is all one file. There are pairs of names and data that I can read fine. I just can't figure out how to parse the header to get all the different node names that the rest of the XML file contains. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help Charles, it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based off of context, it looks like you are working with an XML File saved with `DataSet.WriteXml(string, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)`.  **You should read this file with** [`DataSet.ReadXml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.readxml(v=vs.110).aspx).  Each of the value-pairs are rows in tables.

Example:

```
var rhDs = new DataSet();
rhDs.ReadXml("dat.xml");

foreach (DataTable table in rhDs.Tables)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Table: {0}\r\n", table.TableName);

    foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
    {
        Console.Write("{0}\t", column.ColumnName);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\r\n-----------------------------------------");

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}\t", row[column]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Prints:

```
Table: Doubler_Cal
Freq    Mag
-----------------------------------------
300000000       14.71725
310000000       15.25
320000000       16.25


Table: Tripler_Stuff
Freq    Mag
-----------------------------------------
300000000       13.8
310000000       10.15


Table: This_too_is_possible
Freq    Mag
-----------------------------------------
322000000       17.25
332000000       18.8
334000000       19.15


Table: YetAnotherName
Freq    Mag
-----------------------------------------
322000000       17.25
332000000       18.8
```

---

### Parsing Manually

If you are not working with a saved dataset, the information you present *looks* like an embedded XML schema, but it is not well formed.  You would therefore have some problems getting it to parse by a schema parser. You will have to reference the namespace which must be present elsewhere in the file.

Prints:

```
Doubler_Cal
Tripler_Stuff
This_too_is_possible
YetAnotherName
```

You can also do this with `XmlDocument` via:

```
var xd = new XmlDocument();
xd.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

var names = new XmlNamespaceManager(xd.NameTable);
names.AddNamespace("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
var elementNames = xd.SelectNodes("/NewDataSet/xs:schema/xs:element/xs:complexType/xs:choice/xs:element/@name", names);

foreach (XmlAttribute name in elementNames)
{
    Console.WriteLine(name.Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mitch - I understand now how complex the header is and how much it matters (now). So I re-edited my sample XML File to include the entire header. I seem to have problems with the path part where the node is: "xs:element name". The parser: xd.SelectNodes("/root/NewDataSet/xs:element name/xs:complexType/xs:choice/xs:element name", names) does not like the space between "element" and "name".

Comment: That should be just `xs:element", names)`.  The XPath for that would be `xs:element/@Name`.  The `.Select(s => s.GetAttribute("name"))` is where we retrieve the `name` attribute from the element.

Comment: And the complete XPath would be `/NewDataSet/xs:schema/xs:element/xs:complexType/xs:choice/xs:element/@name`

Comment: @SteveHageman, If this answer has solved the issue, you can mark it "Accepted" by clicking the green checkmark.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help Mitch, you are the best - Your Manual Parsing does indeed work. I owe you a cup of Joe!